# Apache Geode Native Client logs show a connection pool error on starting native client

Tags: geode

We run a native client and I have noticed a `Failed to add endpoint to pool` error in the cache server logs when the client is started.

I setup the logs using:

```
CacheFactory cacheFactory = new CacheFactory();
return cacheFactory
    .Set("log-file", "Geode.log")
    .Set("log-level", "ALL")
    .Set("name", "Dealer")
    .SetPdxReadSerialized(true)
    .Create();
```

The Geode.log file shows the following:

```
[info 2020/09/03 12:40:57.906591 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 11876] ClientMetadataService started for pool MyPool2
[debug 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986018 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] SerializationRegistry::deserialize typeId = -1 dsCode =  1
[debug 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986095 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] closing the connection locator1
[debug 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986117 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] closing the connection locator
[fine 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986205 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] Created new endpoint 1.2.3.4:40404 for pool MyPool2
[error 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986256 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] Failed to add endpoint 1.2.3.4:40404 to pool MyPool2
[debug 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986285 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] ThinClientRedundancyManager::maintainRedundancyLevel(): checking redundant list, size = 0
[debug 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986303 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] ThinClientRedundancyManager::maintainRedundancyLevel(): finding nonredundant endpoints, size = 1
[fine 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986321 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] Recovering subscriptions on endpoint [1.2.3.4:40404] from pool MyPool2
[fine 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986339 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] TcrEndpoint::createNewConnection: connectTimeout = m_needToConnectInLock=59000000 appThreadRequest =0
[debug 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986361 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] Tcrconnection const isSecondary = 0 and isClientNotification = 0, this = 00000202EDBAD790,  conn ref to endopint 1
[finest 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986438 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] Using socket send buffer size of 64240.
[finest 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986465 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] Using socket receive buffer size of 64240.
[debug 2020/09/03 12:40:57.986482 GMT Daylight Time ARGO:15580 25428] Creating plain socket stream
```

Can someone explain why we see the error here? The code that is executed is at [ThinClientPoolDM.cpp](https://github.com/apache/geode-native/blob/88230058a9bf88faf64d5d02cf0512662282161f/cppcache/src/ThinClientPoolDM.cpp#L1991) but the error does not seem to make any difference to the client, which we can see *does* make a connection. Though the server endpoint does not appear to be added to a pool in the `error` state we can see a `fine` message almost immediately after saying `recovering subscriptions on endpoint` and it's the same endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a longstanding bug in this code causing it to log a failure here on success and vice-versa, which is most likely what you're hitting.  This was fixed as part of PR #588 for [GEODE-7930](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-7930), on 4/6/2020.  Please see if you have this fix in your local repo and reply if you do and are still hitting the issue.